# How to make consistent reference labels across `enumerate` and `subfigure` items?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subfloats, labels, enumitem

I have a figure with four subfigures, each corresponding to a subcase in a theorem, labeled (*a*), (*b*)*i*, and (*b*)*ii* respectively using the `enumitem` package (see MWE and illustration below; note the reference style in the paragraph following the theorem).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textnormal{(\emph{\alph*})}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{labelindent=2\parindent,
label=\textnormal{(\emph{\roman*})},ref=\theenumi\textnormal{\emph{\roman*}}}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
There are two cases and three subcases in this theorem:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{itm.a} About the first figure.
\item   About the other figures.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{itm.bi} About the second figure.
    \item \label{itm.bii} About the third figure.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

The theorem talks about \ref{itm.a}, \ref{itm.bi}, and \ref{itm.bii}.

See Figures~\ref{fig.a}, \ref{fig.bi}, and \ref{fig.bii}.

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
A
\caption{The first picture} \label{fig.a}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
BI
\caption{The second picture} \label{fig.bi}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
BII
\caption{The third picture} \label{fig.bii}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Three different pictures.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Since each of the subfigures corresponds exactly to one subcase in the theorem, I would like the subfigures to be labeled the same as the corresponding subcases, i.e., (*a*), (*b*)*i*, and (*b*)*ii*, and the references to these figures should be displayed as such as well. Specifically, I want the subfigure labels to be (*a*), (*b*)*i*, and (*b*)*ii* (instead of (a), (b), and (c)), and thus the last paragraph of the document with the references should read "See Figures 1(*a*), 1(*b*)*i*, and 1(*b*)*ii*."

**How can I do this?** I guess the larger question is **how to make two different things have the same label.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\ref{itm.a}}` inside a subfigure (before the caption) replaces its name with `\ref{itm.a}`, whatever that is. This is also used when referring to the subfigure.

There is a slight complication in that `\ref{itm.a}` comes with parentheses, and when it shows up in the subfigure caption it is by default enclosed in more parentheses. This is fixed in the example below by making `\thesubfigure` include the parentheses.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textnormal{(\emph{\alph*})}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{labelindent=2\parindent,
label=\textnormal{(\emph{\roman*})},ref=\theenumi\textnormal{\emph{\roman*}}}

%% Remove the automatic parentheses and make them part of the label
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
There are two cases and three subcases in this theorem:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{itm.a} About the first figure.
\item   About the other figures.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{itm.bi} About the second figure.
    \item \label{itm.bii} About the third figure.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

The theorem talks about \ref{itm.a}, \ref{itm.bi}, and \ref{itm.bii}.

See Figures~\ref{fig.a}, \ref{fig.bi}, and \ref{fig.bii}.

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\ref{itm.a}}
\centering
A
\caption{The first picture} \label{fig.a}
\end{subfigure}
\quad
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\ref{itm.bi}}
\centering
BI
\caption{The second picture} \label{fig.bi}
\end{subfigure}
\quad
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\ref{itm.bii}}
\centering
BII
\caption{The third picture} \label{fig.bii}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Three different pictures.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    Another subfigure
    \caption{Testing to ensure that captions on other subfigures still show with parentheses}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Testing captions on other figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Of course, if you do this often enough you might want to define a macro for it. The same trick will also work for renaming tables, figures, etc. (using `\thetable`, `\thefigure`, respectively in place of `\thesubfigure`).